Fetching 30k+ Columns with JDBC Cursor - Arithmetic Overflow
I'm encountering an unusual issue while using a JDBC cursor to fetch data from SQL Server. My client needs to retrieve a very large number of columns (over 30,000) from a single table.
Problem: Setting selectMethod="cursor" in the connection properties leads to an SQLServerException with the message

The statement failed due to arithmetic overflow when sending data stream" (SQLState: S0002, vendor code: 4079).

This occurs when attempting to fetch all columns at once.
Tried Solutions:

Increased server resources (without success).
Searched online for solutions but found no relevant results.

Desired Outcome: Is there a way to efficiently fetch a large number of columns (30,000+) using a cursor in JDBC? Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
P.S: using selectMethod = "direct" does work, but I would still like to know if it is possible to do it with "cursor".
package org.example;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement;

public class TryOutUrl {
  public static final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01;databaseName=master;trustServerCertificate=true;";
  public static final String username = "sa";
  public static final String password = "blueSubmarine@345";
  public static final String query = """
    Select t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,
    t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.*,t1.* from "dbo"."MyLargeTable" t1;
    """;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
      Properties info = new Properties();
      info.put("user", username);
      info.put("password", password);
      info.put("selectMethod", "cursor");
      info.put("responseBuffering", "adaptive");

      SQLServerConnection conn = (SQLServerConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);
      SQLServerPreparedStatement ps = (SQLServerPreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      System.out.println("Query successful.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
  }
}


"My client needs to retrieve a very large number of columns (over 30,000) from a single table" This feels like the real problem. I doubt the client "needs" to, and more they think they need to, and what they need is quite different.

A database table in SQL Server cannot have 30k+ columns. I think you mean rows, right? Also, why are you selecting all the columns from [database] table MyLargeTable 24 times in a single [SQL] query?

Also, you state that you need to get 30,000+ from a single table, however, no table supports >30,000 columns in SQL Server. Tables in SQL Server can have at most 1,024 columns, and sparse tables at most 30,000, as noted in the capacity specifications. It's impossible for your table to have 30,001 or more columns. Also a SELECT statement cannot return more than 4,096 columns, as denoted in the same documentation.

It looks like a TDS error, so i have a feeling it's a limitation of the cursor method of fetching data.

@ThomA i think 4096 is limit of individual elements, it seems to be able to do more if you do: t.*

So how about you tell us what you are actually trying to do.

@Charlieface maybe he's doing some of those AI things where you need a lot of parameters

I suspect the difference is that in cursor mode, the table name is passed through TDS in the metadata token, which takes much more space and overflows something inside the TDS stream. you maybe have more luck if you bunge the values by doing some expression of them which erases the table name, for example: i think select *... union all select t1.*...  from yourtable where 1 = 0 might be able to do that (this is of course hacky)

Huh, you're right @siggemannen , I (falsely) assumed that SELECT * would be parsed as SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, .... Column 1024, ... and would result in hitting the limit. Though, I stand by that this feels like an XY Problem.

Are the client's column names May_1990, June_1990..... Apr_2024, May_2024 or some other similar cross-tabbed structure not in Normal Form? I suspect a schema issue if someone thinks they need more than 30,000 columns. I've never seen that kind of a real use case.

Hi everyone,  I am communicating with my client and working to optimize the schema. Meanwhile, just wanted to know if there is anyway to do this with selectMethod = "cursor". I understand the query in the code does not make sense. The exact usecase you can consider is that the user has multiple tables with large number of columns and they are joined together, fetching all rows in necessary in the processing they are doing(some kind of batch process), also there may be large number of rows as well.

Returning 30,000 rows is completely different to 30,000 columns, @forestwalker . Are you confusing the 2?

No, I meant all the rows need to be fetched for all the columns.

What sql server version and jdbc driver version are you using? I wasn't able to replicate your issue in either sql server 2019 nor sql server 2022

sql server 2022. Did you try with selectMethod = cursor??

Yes, i even tried 40k columns

Strange. I think there may be some kind of limitation according to system. Thoughts?

To work around limitations in the number of columns that can be returned to the client, ask SQL Server to bundle the data into one or more JSON documents with a FOR JSON query.  And Stream the JSON to the client, or return it as nvarchar(max) values in a resultset.

Thanks for the answer, but wanted to know if there is anyway to do it in normal result set with selectMethod = 'cursor'. Also could not find any defined hard limits in ms documents. Could you help me understand how the limit is defined?

There may be limits in the client driver, the network protocol, and in the server for parsing or query processing.  It's not worth figuring out.
